# play m3u8 video from laravel storage

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg, streaming, http-live-streaming, m3u8

My question is the same as [how to play m3u8 videos from laravel storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55084850/how-to-play-m3u8-videos-from-laravel-storage) but this one did not get answers.

If I play the video from the public folder it does it without problems.

but if I want to play it from storage this doesn't work.

```
    public function watch(Request $request, Episode $episode)
{

    $video = Storage::disk('videos')->get($episode->video);

    return new Response($video, 200, ['Content-Type' => 'application/x-mpegURL', 'isHls' => true]);
}
```

this is the definition of my disk in config/filesystems.php

```
  'videos' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/videos'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

this is my conversion code (job)

```
     */
public function handle()
{
    $path = $this->episode->id . '.m3u8';
    $lowBitrate  = (new X264 ('aac'))->setKiloBitrate(500)->setVideoCodec('libx264');
    $midBitrate  = (new X264 ('aac'))->setKiloBitrate(1000)->setVideoCodec('libx264');
    $highBitrate = (new X264 ('aac'))->setKiloBitrate(3000)->setVideoCodec('libx264');

    FFMpeg::fromDisk('tmp')->open($this->episode->video)
        ->exportForHLS()
        ->dontSortFormats()
        ->setSegmentLength(10)
        ->toDisk('local')
        ->addFormat($lowBitrate, function($media) {
            $media->addFilter(function ($filters) {
                $filters->resize(new \FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(640, 480));
            });
        })
        ->addFormat($midBitrate, function($media) {
            $media->addFilter(function ($filters) {
                $filters->resize(new \FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(1280, 960));
            });
        })
        ->addFormat($highBitrate, function($media) {
            $media->addFilter(function ($filters) {
                $filters->resize(new \FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(1280, 960));
            });
        })
        ->save($path);

    $this->episode->update([
        'video' => $path,
    ]);

    FFMpeg::cleanupTemporaryFiles();

}
```

Comment: You're using `videos` as disk, have you defined `videos` disk on `config/filesystems.php` file?

Comment: Yes, of course it's defined

Comment: would you please post it?

Comment: I already added it to the question

Comment: and how you store the videos? can you post its code too?

Answer (score 1):

Your `videos` disk configuration is wrong. Try to store your videos this way:

```
$episode->video = $request->file('video')->store('videos', 'local');
```

Then add a new route on `routes/web.php`:

```
Route::get('/episodes/{episode}/watch', 'EpisodeController@watch')->name('episodes.whatch');
```

The try this on your controller:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage

public function watch(Request $request, Episode $episode)
{
    return Storage::disk('local')->response(
        $episode->video,
        "optional_name_or_null",
        [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-mpegURL',
            'isHls' => true
        ]
    );

    //or alternatively use this one:
    /*
    return response()->file(
        Storage::disk('local')->path($episode->video),
        [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-mpegURL',
            'isHls' => true
        ]
    );
    */
}
```

Now you can access your video on: 'http://your-domain.com/episodes/1/watch'

> Note: Playing HLS/DASH videos are not natively supported on most of the
>   browsers, try to use third-party plugins [like this one](https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming) to play
>   these video formats.

Comment: thanks for the answer, try what you told me, storing the files on the local disk

https://i.imgur.com/MtoRQOP.png

and with
return Storage :: disk ('local') -> response ($ episode-> video); I get the text from the file

https://i.imgur.com/KVAQ0ZT.png

with return response () -> file (
         Storage :: disk ('local') -> path ($ episode-> video),
         [
             'Content-Type' => 'application / x-mpegURL',
             'isHls' => true
         ]
     );

I get the same result as before, it doesn't play.

I will add my conversion code to the question.

Comment: @Jennsen what if you set header on first one? I've updated my answer, plz try again.